# For each loop to compare dates in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, date

im trying to check dates from user input (check-in and check-out dates), so first i made a function to get every date between the date range selected by the client.

```
function createRange($startDate, $endDate) {
    $tmpDate = new DateTime($startDate);
    $tmpEndDate = new DateTime($endDate);

    $outArray = array();
    do {
        $outArray[] = $tmpDate->format('Y-m-d');
    } while ($tmpDate->modify('+1 day') <= $tmpEndDate);

    return $outArray;
}
```

Next i made a function to get availability from my database for each dates:

```
function rleft($fromdate, $todate){
    //DB Access
    require('/some/where/over/the/rainbow/db.php');
    //url parameters
    require ('/some/where/over/the/rainbow/param.php');
        //Hotel Room Data
            $customroom = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM hotel_room_type WHERE room_type_id = '1'");
            $customroomtotal = mysqli_num_rows($customroom);
            $customroomData = mysqli_fetch_array($customroom);
            $roominventory = $customroomData['room_type_inventory'];
            //availiability list
            $customavailable = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM booking_check_avilability WHERE room_type_id = '1' AND check_in_date = '$fromdate' AND check_out_date = '$todate'");
            $customavailabletotal = mysqli_num_rows($customavailable);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            if($customavailabletotal > 0) {
                while($customavailableData = mysqli_fetch_array($customavailable))  {         
                        $inventariodisponible = $roominventory - $customavailableData['total_room'] -$customavailableData['blocked_inventory'];
                }
            } mysqli_free_result($customavailable);
            mysqli_close(conn);
            return $inventariodisponible;
}
```

my database has 2 dates range for every date: for example to know the availability of 2017/07/01, the database has this value in 2 columns:

```
check_in_date | check_out_date
2017/07/01    | 2017/07/02
```

with that in mind

i made another function which gets the array with all the dates between dates selected and asks for availability for each date in my rleft function.

```
function inout($fromdate, $todate){
 require ('/some/where/over/the/rainbow/param.php');   
    $datearray = createRange("$fromdate", "$todate");
    foreach ($datearray as $value) {
        $from = $value;
        $to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value . "+1 days"));
        $left = rleft($from, $to);
    }
    echo $left;
    }
```

// in param.php we have:

```
function prgrp(){
    $pgrp = "preg_replace('/[^-]a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', ";
}
//Parametros URL de fechas
    $datefrom = prgrp() . $_GET['checkin'];
    $dateto = prgrp() . $_GET['checkout'];
    $fromdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datefrom));
    $todate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateto));
    $checkin = new DateTime($fromdate);
    $checkout = new DateTime($todate);
    $countdays = $checkin->diff($checkout);
    $cntd = $countdays->format('%d');
    $add1day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datefrom . "+1 days"));
```

if i echo $left; i should get the values of how many rooms are available for each date of the array... which i want to be displayed in a list. to show the client which dates aren't available between the dates selected. But for some reason i don't get anything at all.

I'm really noob with php and coding, so please if i made some stupid mistake please forgive me and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `prgrp` is doing nothing. I'd think you could use the mysql `between` to pull the date range, I'm not really clear of your db structure though.

Comment: prgrp true that, i forgot to return the value, but anyway... it won't affect the rest of the code, and my db structure is:

simple:

room_id | check_in_date | check_out_date | blocked_inventory | total_room

where room_id is the id for the room requested, check_in and out dates are dates one after the other like 1 day after de check_in_date is the check_out date for every day between the date range selected by the client... blocked _inventory is the rooms blocked in the backend, and total room, is the rooms already booked.

Comment: i'm not sure if that helps or not...

Comment: There are many things wrong with `prgrp`. I think you could do something like `select count(*) as da_count from table where submitted_date between check_in_date and check_out_date having da_count < total_number_of_rooms` then you'll know there is at least one room available for the range they selected.

Comment: I would forget about all the php code for now and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query